# Unable to trigger mouse event in Capybara test

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am using Capybara 1.0.0, and I have a link in my page which gets visible when mouse hover over that block. So I want to trigger mouse over in test so that I can click that hidden link.
I googled it, but couldn't find the solution that suits me. Can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've chosen to use Capybara webkit, and sadly I had to resort to executing javascript using jQuery:

```
page.execute_script('$(".ClassSelector").trigger("hover")')
```

Comment: People need to stop suggesting this. There are always ways to do this using capybara, the driver, or the native element. Execute script executes immediately, and does not respect any kind of scope.

Comment: Can you provide example code for each of the methods you describe here?

Answer (score 13):

This blog has the answer:

http://aokolish.me/blog/2012/01/22/testing-hover-events-with-capybara

```
page.find('#element').trigger(:mouseover)
```

This doesn't work with the selenium driver though:

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#trigger-instance_method

Answer (score 9):

[This commit](https://github.com/twalpole/capybara/commit/2fe67b4cdf7bf86a1495982c0bd5c51564120ca1) added the hover method. It has the advantage of including css hover effects on elements.

Usage:

```
find('#posts .post .comments .comment').hover
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble getting this to work as well. There's a lot of conflicting information on the web. Here's how I did it:

Setting: rails 3.2.1, capybara 1.1.2, rspec 2.8.0, selenium-webdriver 2.20.0

`page.execute_script "$('tr.user-#{user.id}').trigger('mouseover')"`

This will cause the previously hidden links to appear (by virtue of jQuery's hover function), which are then accessible for `have_link` and `click_link`.

Note: you do **not** want to write `page.evaluate_script` as this won't work.

---

Edit: Well I just realized that @kelly-sutton's solution is the same as mine. So I can confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

For visibility problems sometimes it helps to change window size for poltergeist. I've done it
in spec_helper.rb

```
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, window_size: [1280, 600])
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as using either `find('#element').hover` or `page.execute_script "$('#element_2').trigger('mouseover');"` one must also pass `js: true` to the `describe` block in order to turn on javascript (unless you've done that in your configuration). This tripped me up for a bit.