# is there any Alternative method for trigger in capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara, mouseover

I tried the following code:

```
page.find("#{element_name}").trigger(:mouseover)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError (Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError)
```

I am using selenium web-driver.

According to the following URL trigger is not implemented in selenium web-driver:
[Unable to trigger mouse event in Capybara test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725048/problem-with-triggering-mouse-event-in-capybara-test)

Is there any alternative to method to perform mouse hover an element instead of using trigger in capybara?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`page.execute_script(some_javascript)`, in particular `some_javascript = "$(selector).trigger(event)"`. This will work on all drivers which are js-capable.  Note that `page.evaluate_script(some_javascript)` could work too, but it's not guaranteed and discouraged (use `evaluate_script` only when script returns primitives).

I mean: execute client-side scripts which does what you want (trigger events).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using capybara-webkit. I am using capybara 1.1.2 and Selenium-webdriver 2.25.0. is there any Alternative method for trigger in capybara? with this configuration.

Comment: @Manikandan: What I wrote is executing raw JavaScript.  Although it looks very similar to your piece of code, it's different.  It does not rely on Capybara's finders and `#trigger` method as in your example.  This is the simplest solution and it will work with every JS-capable driver.  If it does not work to you, then you have problems with running JS at all.

Comment: @Manikandan: Oops, I forgot about quotes around string, what made my answer a bit confusing.  `some_javascript` is a string containing arbitrary piece of JavaScript code to be executed with `#execute_script`, which is supported in every JS-capable driver.